# Effect of EWG on groups undergoing decarboxylation

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

I have been reading Peter's Sykes and there I came across certain compounds which show decarboxylation. 
My doubt is that how the acidity of the groups attached to the carboxyl groups will help in decarboxylation. 
For example we have one EWG and one EDG then which will show faster decarboxylation.

I am quite aware of the mechanism but somehow I can't relate here.

Comment: EWG stabilise anions. The key step of decarboxylation is the formation of an anion from the loss of CO2.

Comment: Yes but here we are proceeding via 6 membered cyclic TS not by anion formation

Comment: A diagram would assist

Comment: What I mean to say is the decarboxylation mechanism at higher temperature where we assume co2 leaves

Comment: Anyone can help?